# Debugging with radare2 using two terminals

Tags: debugging, linux, radare2

I have been trying to figure this out for quite some time now, and would really need some help. Firstly, some intro:

I am running the newest version of radare2 from Github on a 64bit Ubuntu 16.04 and have the following sample program `r2_test.cpp`:

```
#include <cstdio>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    int num;

    while (1)
    {
        printf("Enter a number: ");
        scanf("%d", &num);
        printf("You entered: %d\n", num);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

What I am trying to achieve is to debug this program using radare2 and two terminals in a way that I run radare2 in terminal window `T1` and have the programs input/output in terminal window `T2`. After some research I figured that this should probably be done with the help of `rarun2` tool.

So, for my first try I read the [man page](https://github.com/radare/radare2/blob/master/man/rarun2.1#L139) for rarun2, specifically the part with redirecting IO to another terminal and after identifying the `T2` terminal as `/dev/pts/17` I created the following `test.rr2` file:

```
#!/usr/bin/rarun2
stdio=/dev/pts/17
```

In `T2` terminal I've then run `sleep 999999` and in terminal `T1` I run `r2 -R test.rr2 -d a.out` and when executing the command `dc` inside radare2, the programs input/output is in terminal `T1` which is not what I wanted. I've also tried variations like making `test.rr2` equal

```
#!/usr/bin/rarun2
stdin=/dev/pts/17
stdout=/dev/pts/17
```

or

```
#!/usr/bin/rarun2
stdio=/dev/pts/17
stdin=/dev/pts/17
stdout=/dev/pts/17
```

but the result was always the same.

For my second try, after some research and reading, I tried running the radare2 in the following way: `r2 -d rarun2 program=a.out stdio=/dev/pts/17`. With this I've achieved redirecting the IO to terminal `T2`, but the process which gets debugged inside radare2 is the rarun2 tool and since my knowledge of Linux and reverse engineering on it is not that good, I don't really know how to proceed to debugging the `a.out` process.

So, to summarize, I would really appreciate if someone could share here if this kind of debugging can be done with radare2 and, if it can, how to achieve it? I've also tried it with using `nc`, but I haven't made any progress to this topic with it.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

It is actually very simple and works for me just fine as you can see in the following gif:

[image: Direct link]

---

First you need to figure out the `tty` of the terminal you want to redirect the `STDIO` to (a.k.a Terminal 2, *T2*).
You can do this  by simply execute:

```
$ tty
/dev/pts/2
```

This `tty` will soon be used on the `rarun2` profile file.
Meantime, let's put *T2* to sleep by using `sleep 999999`.

Moving to *Terminal 1*, let's create a simple `rarun2` profile with the following content:

```
#!/usr/bin/rarun2
stdio=/dev/pts/2
```

We configured `stdio` to transfer the *standard input and output* to *T2*.
Now let's execute our program with the profile we've just created:

```
$ r2 -e dbg.profile=profile.rr2 -d a.out  
Process with PID 14074 started...
= attach 14074 14074
bin.baddr 0x00400000
Using 0x400000
Assuming filepath /tmp/re/a.out
asm.bits 64
 -- Mind that the 'g' in radare is silent
[0x7f9654e0fd80]>
```

(*The same can be done using:* `r2 -r profile.rr2 -d a.out`)
The program successfully loaded in debug mode. Now just for the example, let's put a *breakpoint* on the second call to `printf` and start the program using `dc`. In the *gif* I was not creating a breakpoint.

```
[0x7f9654e0fd80]> db 0x00400580
[0x7f9654e0fd80]> dc
Selecting and continuing: 14074
```

Now *T2* gives us the output and asks for our input:

```
Enter a number:
```

After we send it a digit our breakpoint on *T1* hit:

```
hit breakpoint at: 400580
[0x00400580]>
```

We can now continue the execution using `dc`, the loop would continue forever and the Standard Input and Output will be in T2.

Comment: Ok, so the problem was that Sublime doesn't automatically add a "newline" character to my profile.rr2 file. Also, I only tried with the -R option and with it it doesn't work. I still don't understand why it doesn't work with -R but does with -e dbg.profile=...Anyway, I know now how to make it work and thanks a lot. If you have time, can you check if it will work for you with the -R.

Comment: It works just fine with -R as I mentioned in the post :) I checked it few times. Glad I was able to help!

Comment: +1 for gif demo, very clarifying