# Is there any way to display the standard input and output of a program to Cutter's console while debugging?

Tags: debugging, radare2

So it's easy to transfer the standard input and output in radare2 to a new terminal  using rarun2, here's how:
[Debugging with radare2 using two terminals](https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/16428/debugging-with-radare2-using-two-terminals/16430#16430)

i was wondering if i can use rarun2 with Cutter  or even display the program's output in the cutter console?

Edit: I'm using Ubuntu 18.04

Comment: What is your host OS?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Good news! In Cutter v1.10 (December 20, 2019) the team [introduced](https://twitter.com/r2gui/status/1208106040954359808) native and remote debugger support. By default, the STDIO of the debuggee is redirected to the Console Widget inside Cutter.

**Downloading the latest release**
To download the recent version of Cutter you can go to the [official website](https://cutter.re) and click on the Download button. It will automatically detect your OS and give you the right file to download.

**Debugging**
Open Cutter and choose a file to analyze. On the following dialog configure the settings as you wish, you can leave it as-it for the defaults.

On the interface of Cutter you can start debugging by **either** of the following ways:

1. Press <kbd>F9</kbd> to execute native debug
2. Click the green button at the top of the interface to start Debug
   [image]
3. Click on the "Debug" menu and choose Start Debug
   [image]

Then, click Play and the program will run. On Linux, you will see the STDIO in the Console Widget (open it from Windows -> Console). You can interact with it and send it input.

[image]