# Using output of a command as argument in radare2

Tags: radare2

I'm trying to use the output of a command as argument for my program that i'm trying to debug.

I created the following profile, similar to using [a command output for `stdin`](https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/23359/radare2-debugging-how-do-i-pipe-a-programs-output-to-anothers-input)

```
$ cat profile.rr2
#!/usr/bin/rarun2
arg1=!cat payload
```

However, this does not add a argument and gives the following warning if the debug process is started using the profile

```
WARNING: r_str_trim_tail: assertion 'str' failed (line 173)
```

Is it even possible to define the output of a command as argument with a profile?